# read text file from Azure FileShare in a method

Tags: c#, filestream, asp.net-core-3.1, azure-storage-files

I want to read the contents of a csv file that I have in my FileShare on my storageaccount in Azure, using `Azure.Storage.Files.Shares` library.

I am able to connect to the file using the `ShareFileClient`, but how can I then read the contents and process them (append a new line), in my code?

```
ShareFileClient file = ConnectToFile();
Steam content = await file.OpenReadAsync(true);
// gives a Stream object, that I cannot get to work to get the content.
```

What are the next steps to stream the contents of this file? I'm stuck at trying to get the read action to work with something like

```
using (Steam stream = new Stream() )
{       
 
    // The actions to read the stream go here 
}
```

Any suggestions on how this could be achieved?

Comment: Do you have any other concerns? If you have no other concerns, could you please accept it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the issue, please refer to the following code

```
 // read
            using (var stream = await file.OpenReadAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream)) {
                // read csv file one line by line 
                while (!reader.EndOfStream) {
                  var line =await  reader.ReadLineAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                    Console.WriteLine(line);
                }
            }

            //write
            ShareFileProperties properties = await file.GetPropertiesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            var myPosition = properties.ContentLength;
            var newData = "42,11,58, \"N\",85,12,45, \"W\", \"Worcester\", ND"+Environment.NewLine;
            var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(newData);
            await file.SetHttpHeadersAsync(myPosition + bytes.Length);
            using (var writer = await file.OpenWriteAsync(overwrite: false, position:(myPosition -1)).ConfigureAwait(false)) {
               
                await writer.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                await writer.FlushAsync();
            }
```